# Text changed to graphics, still selectable in PDF?

Tags: pdf

I have this PDF ebook with selectable text - the handwriting - but there is no such font embedded and the letters are all different, so it's not actually a font. How is this possible?

I've worked with CorelDraw and Adobe Acrobat, but I can't understand how this works.

The left side of the picture shows the document properties, the right side shows a page of the PDF file and I selected the last 3 rows. I can copy and paste that to a text file, no problem. How was this achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities but the most likely is the text is being converted to outlines/paths or vectors. Some software such as Adobe InDesign and other print design apps allow you to 'flatten' a font based text into vector or paths, meaning the original font isn't required to be embedded or installed on the system. The original text data is however still present and able to be copied into a text field or word processor.

Comment: So the file contains both the handwriting font (that is converted to curves and then edited some more) AND the original text data? Can that happen?

Comment: Another alternative is that you have the font visible in your example and it's being substituted for the missing font. Without knowing exactly what the PDF was intended to look like it can be difficult to ascertain.

Comment: To answer your previous question, yes that can happen :)

Comment: Thanks. It's this book: https://www.chroniclebooks.com/products/i-like-you-i-love-you

I haven't used InDesign, so I didn't know you can outline/vector a font and ALSO keep the original text data, it's mindblowing to me, really! As a CorelDraw user, you can only covert text to curves/vector and all text/font data disappears from the file.

Comment: The book deffinitely looks like it should, so it's probably your first answer - they exported from InDesign keeping both the outlines and the text data. I still don't understand how that works in the PDF file, since the text data is invisible until the text is selected :)

Comment: Yes it's definitely the correct font. It works in a similar way to this SVG based example, where essentially the text data is anchored to each vector based shape (curve/outline/path etc): https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedTextFills/index17.html

In a very basic form it just holds the information telling your PDF reader 'this area of page should be read as this character when selected'.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain everything!